# remove duplicated rows

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have a file with bunch of rows, here is how it looks like (just a head of file):

```
    "chrom" "startA" "stopA" "genesA" "startB" "stopB" "genesB" "test"
    1 315121 317607 "gene2" 315521 317204 "gene3" 1684
    1 315521 317204 "gene3" 315121 317607 "gene2" 1684
    1 407644 408993 "gene4" 408421 409504 "gene5" 573
    1 407644 408993 "gene4" 408616 410013 "gene6" 378
    1 408421 409504 "gene5" 407644 408993 "gene4" 573
    1 408421 409504 "gene5" 408616 410013 "gene6" 889
    1 408616 410013 "gene6" 407644 408993 "gene4" 378
    1 408616 410013 "gene6" 408421 409504 "gene5" 889
    1 408616 410013 "gene6" 409682 411483 "gene7" 332
....
```

There are some identical rows (the same pair of genes, just the order of start and stop positions differ, but they are exactly the same) which I need to remove the repeated row.
For example:

```
1 315121 317607 "gene2" 315521 317204 "gene3" 1684
1 315521 317204 "gene3" 315121 317607 "gene2" 1684
```

are the same, it is genes 2 and 3 combination just in a different order and I want to remove one of them.

Here is my desired output:

```
"chrom" "startA" "stopA" "genesA" "startB" "stopB" "genesB" "test"
    1 315121 317607 "gene2" 315521 317204 "gene3" 1684
    1 407644 408993 "gene4" 408421 409504 "gene5" 573
    1 407644 408993 "gene4" 408616 410013 "gene6" 378
    1 408421 409504 "gene5" 408616 410013 "gene6" 889
    1 408616 410013 "gene6" 409682 411483 "gene7" 332
```

Is there any idea how I can do this task? Thanks

Comment: Are the duplicities always adjacent? How is the file sorted?

Comment: This looks like genomic data. Should we assume that the amount of data is _huge_?

Comment: @ Kusalananda, yes .. but it not super huge. I have approximately 300K rows in my file.

Comment: @choroba, no they are not

Comment: Seems to me that from the data provided, the last field gives the idea whether the record is unique.  Is that correct?

Comment: @unxnut, no it is not uniq .. it is the size of overlapping between any pair of genes .. and there are the same size of overlap but in different pairs of genes

Comment: Would `awk '!seen[$4"" < $7 ? $4 OFS $7 : $7 OFS $4]++'` work or to you need to look at other columns than the 4th and 7th?

Comment: @Stéphane Chazelas, Yup ... seems that you code does exactly what I want :)

Comment: _@Anna1364_, is this an accurate description? "I need to remove rows where
there's a match of field 1 and a match of field 8 AND either
fields 2-4 match another line and fields 5-7 match another line OR fields 2-4 match fields 5-7 of another line and fields 5-7 match fields 2-4 of another line"?

Comment: @ K7AAY, I am not really sure if I understand what you are trying to say , complicated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try:

```
awk '{key = $4 < $7 ? $4 SUBSEP $7 : $7 SUBSEP $4} !seen[key]++' file
```

That stores the minimum necessary to remove the duplicate records.

`!seen[key]++` is a "famous" awk idiom to print a record only for the first time "key" is seen.

Comment: I swear I did this before I read Stéphane's comment...

Answer (score 0):

You can order the triplets of columns 2-3-4 and 5-6-7 by the value in the first column:

```
perl -lane '@F[1,2,3,4,5,6] = @F[4,5,6,1,2,3] if $F[1] > $F[4]; print "@F"'
```

Then you can just run `sort -u` to remove the duplicities (but you need to special case the column names).

Comment: I have ~300K rows

Comment: Is it too slow?

Answer (score 0):

Assuring in each line:

- no space at up to first field
- 1 space exact in between field
- no space at last field

by gnu sed, your data in 'data' file;

```
sed -nE ':s G;/(\w+\s)(\w+\s)(\w+\s)(\S+\s)(\w+\s)(\w+\s)(\S+\s)(\w+)\n(.+\n)*\1\w+\s\6\7\w+\s\3\4\8/b; h;P' data
```